# How do you use § instead of page number?

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I am using `biblatex`. When using the cite command `\cite[3]{xx}` I would like it to print `§ 3 xx` instead of `p.3 xx` for some citations. For others I want to cite pages. How can I do this?

Comment: I believe that `\cite[\S~3]{xx}` will work.

Comment: Or you can set the "pagination" field of your source data to `section`, and biblatex will do it automatically.

Comment: @PaulStanley The `pagination` method is good if *all* citation of that work has the form “§ 3” (or any other number.

Comment: That was easy! Thanks a lot to both of you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the `pagination` entry of a source to `section`, `biblatex` will use § in place of `p.`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{testbook,
  author = {Peter Plum},
  title  = {Sectional Interests},
  date   = {2014},
  publisher = {PubCo},
  pagination = {section},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite[3]{testbook}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{IEEEexample.bib}
\begin{document}
foo~\cite[§\,3]{IEEEexample:beebe_archive}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]